# Extremely long execution time on Magento code snippet

Tags: php, magento

So, I'm trying to display color swatches on our grid page.

**Without this code, the page renders in around 3 seconds.**

**With it, it jumps to 12-15 seconds.**

```
if($_product->isConfigurable())
{
    $cIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProductIds($_product); // Get all associated product ids
    // Pull a list of attributes we need for each simple product
    $cProd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$cIds))
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('color','color_family','color_tile','small_image','entity_id'))
                ->setOrder("size")
                ->load();

    $colors = array();
    $swatches = "";
    foreach($cProd as $_cProd)
    {
        if($_cProd->isSaleable()) // check if it's able to be sold
        {
            $c=$_cProd->getColor();
            if(!isset($colors[$c])) // check if we've seen this color before
            {
                $swatches .= "<div class = 'swatch'><img src='/media/catalog/product/".$_cProd->getColorTile()."' title='".$_cProd->getAttributeText("color")."' full='".$_cProd->getSmallImage()."' onmouseover='switchColor(this,\"mainimage-".$pid."\")'></div>";
                $colors[$c] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried grouping the collection, by switching `->load()` to `->group('color')->getSelect()`, but that would throw an error or return a blank set.

I've tried multiple approaches, but I can't speed it up any more than this.  What am I missing something? Is there a different approach I can try?

Comment: Does this code run in a loop? If so, how many iterations?

Answer (score 0):

This is madness. You are loading a collection for every product of your list so you end up with maybe 20 or 30 times running the foreach loop after having expensively loaded the collection 20 or 30 times.

Approach 1:

```
/**
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @return Varien_Data_Collection
 */
public function getFastUsedProducts(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, Array $attributes = array())
{
    $catalogResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

    if ($catalogResource->isEnabledFlat()) {
        $resource = Mage::getResourceSingleton('xxx/catalog_product_type_configurable');
        $productRows = $resource->getFastUsedProducts($product, $attributes);

        $products = new Varien_Data_Collection();
        if (!empty($productRows)) {
            foreach ($productRows as $productData) {
                $productData['id'] = $productData['entity_id'];

                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $product->setData($productData);

                $products->addItem($product);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // FALLBACK TO SLOW RETRIEVAL
        $products = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
    }

    return $products;
}
```

and the resource model for getFastUsedProducts:

```
public function getFastUsedProducts(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, Array $attributes = array())
    {
        if (!in_array('entity_id', $attributes)) $attributes[] = 'entity_id';

        /** @var Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql $readConnection */
        $readConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection(Mage_Core_Model_Resource::DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE);

        /* @var $select Varien_Db_Select */
        $select = $readConnection
        ->select()
        ->from(
        array(
                    'r' => Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_relation')->getMainTable()
        ),
        array('r.child_id')
        )
        ->where('r.parent_id = ?', (int) $product->getId());

        $childIds = $readConnection->fetchCol($select);

        if (empty($childIds)) return NULL;

        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat $flatTable */
        $flatTable = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_flat');

        $availableAttributes = array_intersect($attributes, $flatTable->getAllTableColumns());

        /* @var $select Varien_Db_Select */
        $select = $readConnection
        ->select()
        ->from(
        Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_flat')->getMainTable(),
        $availableAttributes
        )
        ->where('entity_id IN (?)', $childIds);


        $productRows = $readConnection->fetchAll($select);

        return $productRows;
    }

/**
     * Retrieve simples grouped by an attribute code
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @param $attributeCode
     * @return array
     */
    public function getGroupedSimples(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $attributeCode, Array $selectAttributes)
    {
        if (isset($this->_groupedSimplesMap[$product->getId()][$attributeCode])) {
            return $this->_groupedSimplesMap[$product->getId()][$attributeCode];
        }

        $index = array();

        $simples = Mage::getSingleton('xxx/catalog_product_type_configurable')->getFastUsedProducts($product, $selectAttributes);

        foreach ($simples as $simple) {
            $value = $simple->getData($attributeCode);
            if ($value == '' || isset($index[$value])) continue;

            $index[$value] = $simple;
        }

        $this->_groupedSimplesMap[$product->getId()][$attributeCode] = $index;

        return $index;
    }
```

and:

```
<?php if ($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) : ?>
<?php $_colorSimples = $this->helper('xxx/product_type_configurable')->getGroupedSimples($_product, 'color'); ?>
<?php $_showSidebar = count($_colorSimples) > 1; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div
    class="item-wrap <?php echo $_product->getTypeId(); ?><?php if ($_showSidebar) : ?> sb<?php endif; ?>">
    <div class="item-inner-wrap">
    <?php if ($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) : ?>
    <?php if ($_showSidebar) : ?>
        <div class="additional-info simples-wrap">
            <ul class="simples">
            <?php foreach ($_colorSimples as $_simple) : ?>
                <li class="simple-item"
                    data-product-id="<?php echo $_simple->getId(); ?>"><img
                    src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_simple, 'thumbnail')->resize(46); ?>"
                    data-grid-src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_simple, 'small_image')->resize(226); ?>"
                    data-zoom-image="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_simple, 'small_image')->resize(640); ?>"
                    width="46" height="46"
                    alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_simple, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
....
```